# Question on varying the Ricci tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, differentiation, variational-calculus

When varying the Ricci tensor, there’s an in-between step that allows for example
$$\delta\left(\partial_{\alpha}\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\phantom{\alpha}\beta\gamma}\right)= \partial_{\alpha}\left(\delta\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\phantom{\alpha}\beta\gamma}\right) $$

Why is such a swap allowed?

Comment: It's just how it always isin  the calculus of variations:  $\delta[f'(x)]= [\delta f(x)]'$ because $f'(x)-g'(x)= [f(x)-g(x)]'$.

Comment: This is not in general true in the context of GR, since the derivative operator itself varies along with the metric.  Are you by chance looking at a derivation of the *linearized* Einstein equations (where the Christoffel symbols vanish in the background)?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert it’s a partial derivative. What you are saving applies only to covariant derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

1. The variation denoted by $\delta$ is also a kind of derivative that acts on functionals ( function of functions). Since derivatives are in general commutative we can swap the partial derivative $\partial$ to $\delta$.
2. The summation due to $\alpha$ remains the same even after swaping the derivatives. The only difference being the order of derivatives are changed to $\partial \delta$ for each term in summation.

Comment: This is not necessarily true in the context of GR, since the derivative operator is itself being varied along with the metric.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The derivative operator being the coordinate basis vector field does not get varied with the metric. And neither does e.g. the Lie derivative. You must have meant e.g. the covariant derivative, wherein the metric variation comes through varying the Christoffel symbols.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is independent from varying the Ricci tensor, so I'll talk about this more generally. The question is whether the derivative of a variation $\partial \delta f(x)$ is the same as the variation of the derivative $\delta(\partial f(x))$. We can use the chain rule:

$$\delta (\partial f(x))=\int dy \frac{\delta (\partial f(x))}{\delta f(y)}\delta f(y)$$

Now $\frac{\delta (\partial f(x))}{\delta f(y)}=\partial_x\delta(x-y)$, so

$$\delta (\partial f(x))=\int dy \partial_x\delta(x-y)\delta f(y)=\partial \delta f(x)$$

Comment: This is not necessarily true in the context of GR, since the derivative operator is itself being varied along with the metric.

Comment: @michaelseifert the derivative that appears in OPs post is not a covariant derivative. Covariant derivation doesn't even make sense on the Christoffel symbols.